# MS Access 2007: Using SQL to Transpose rows to columns

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, transform

SQL newbie here. I have table setup as the following (my apologies for the poor formatting):

Cycle ID....UBCI....chemo_cycle....csf....rsn_no_csf

57.............18001...1......................N.......N  
58.............18001...2......................N.......N
59.............22002...1......................Y........null

I'd like to convert it into the following format:

UBCI....chemo_cycle1....chemo_cycle2....csf1....csf2....rsn_no_csf1....rsn_no_csf2  
18001...1.........................2.........................N........N........N.....................N
22002...1.........................null......................Y........null.....null..................null

There can be up to 26 chemo_cycles per UBCI. I tried some of the other suggestions, but wasn't familiar enough with SQL to work out some of the finer details. Again, apologies for the formatting. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

-Omar

Comment: You need to give more details on where the #2s come from, how are they derived from the above table.

Comment: Did you try the Cross Tab Query Wizard

Comment: is order of the original table significant?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see to do this conveniently in Access is with four queries. I do not think you can use crosstab queries as subqueries, so:

Query 1: cc

```
TRANSFORM First(TableQ.chemo_cycle) AS FirstOfchemo_cycle
SELECT TableQ.UBCI
FROM TableQ
GROUP BY TableQ.UBCI
PIVOT "CC " & [chemo_cycle];
```

Query 2: csf

```
TRANSFORM First(TableQ.csf) AS FirstOfcsf
SELECT TableQ.UBCI
FROM TableQ
GROUP BY TableQ.UBCI
PIVOT "csf " & [chemo_cycle];
```

Query 3: rsn

```
TRANSFORM First(TableQ.rsn_no_csf) AS FirstOfrsn_no_csf
SELECT TableQ.UBCI
FROM TableQ
GROUP BY TableQ.UBCI
PIVOT "rsn " & [chemo_cycle];
```

Final query:
The columns [cc 1] to [cc 26] will show in the design window, and can be added, here they are indicated by <...>

```
SELECT CC.UBCI, 
       CC.[CC 1], 
       CC.[CC 2], 
       <...>
       csf.[csf 1], 
       csf.[csf 2], 
       <...>
       rsn.[rsn 1], 
       rsn.[rsn 2]
       <...>
FROM (CC INNER JOIN csf 
ON CC.UBCI = csf.UBCI) 
INNER JOIN rsn 
ON csf.UBCI = rsn.UBCI;
```